# Ruby -v showing the wrong version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I installed Ruby with homebrew [following these steps](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan)

everything was great but then I found out the developer i'm working with used Ruby 2.3.0 and when I try to run rails server to get started, it complains about that whole move from Big Int to Integer .

So after some research and the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903202/ruby-on-rails-rails-server-exits-immediately-after-starting-systemstackerror) it indeed seems the right approach is to use 2.3 (wish the developer told me that initially).

I installed 2.3.0, but when I type ruby -v it still shows up as 2.4. I even used rbenv uninstall but it still says 2.4.

I'm still learning the basics so was hoping someone could maybe point me in the right direction on how to get it to register as 2.3 instead.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I noticed was that despite how many times I reinstalled, it never seemed to work, so I went with installing RVM. After doing this, I didn't notice much difference by way of what was installed, but it seemed to work afterwards (it even let me switch versions and typing ruby -v showed the correct set version).

My only guess is I can chalk this up to just missing a few installation steps during my initial rbenv setup and it was not due to rbenv itself.

tl;dr:

I probably messed up the installation or didn't run a command with elevated permissions or something, because going through the process again (albeit for rvm instead of rbenv) sorted out my problem.

Thanks for your time and help in this matter!

Comment: `ruby-install` and `chruby` is simplest & best IMO

Answer (score 1):

run `rbenv versions` to list all versions

then run `rbenv global VERSION_NUMBER_YOU WANT`

Comment: I think it's just OP's typo, he's trying to type ruby -v but somehow it turns out to be rails -v

Comment: So I did that, but when I type ruby -v, it still shows ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin15] and subsequently when I run rails, it messes up based on the above (the 2.4 version / Big Int)